# Lightning datatable rows not retained after clicking back button

Tags: lightning-web-components

**I have a multiple screen wizard,after selecting records from the datatable I click next after that when I click back button the records should still be checked but that's not happening in my case.**

*Selected Rows*
[image]

*After clicking next and then back button above selected rows are not retained*
[image]

**.HTML**

```
<template if:false={fieldError}>
                <lightning-datatable id="searchTable" key-field="id" data={data} columns={columns} 
                    onrowselection={getSelectedRowLength} selected-rows={selectedRows}>
                </lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

**.JS**

```
getSelectedRowLength(event) {
        this.selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows.map(row => row.Id);
        console.log('this.selectedRows : '+this.selectedRows);
}

 handleNextButton(event) {
       
        var getselectedStep = this.selectedStep;
        if (getselectedStep === 'Step1') {
            this.selectedStep = 'Step2';
        }
        else if (getselectedStep === 'Step2') {
            this.selectedStep = 'Step3';
        }
        else if (getselectedStep === 'Step3') {
            this.selectedStep = 'Step4';
        }


        if (this.currentStep === 1) {
            getfieldsContain({ objectName: this.selectedObject }).then(result => {
                if (result) {
                    this.fieldError = true;
                    this.fieldError = result + ' Field does not exist on the ' + this.selectedObject;
                } else {
                    getSearchRecords({
                        objectName: this.selectedObject, inputValue: this.searchName,
                        selectedCheckbox: this.selectedObjectFieldValue
                    }).then(result => {
                        if (result) {
                            this.fieldError = false;
                            this.columns = result.columns;
                            this.data = result.data;
                        }
                    })
                }
            })

        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `selected-rows` property of the `lightning-datatable` to get and store the selected rows in some property and map that property to `selected-rows` property of `lightning-datatable`.

Also please note that you don't need to explicitly query the element to get selected rows. You can get that in `event.detail.selectedRows`.

**JS**

```
selectedRows = [];

//...

getSelectedRowLength(event){
  console.log("event.detail.selectedRows", event.detail.selectedRows)
  this.selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows.map(row => row.Id);
  console.log(this.selectedRows);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<lightning-datatable id="searchTable" key-field="Id" data={data} columns={columns}
    onrowselection={getSelectedRowLength}
    selected-rows={selectedRows}>
</lightning-datatable>
```

As you will be storing the selected rows in the property, you won't lose the selected rows. You can store this in the same component or the container component based on your use case.
Check out the live playground [here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/kI5yIfDWTXH3ZzlYhA02/src/app.html).

Comment: I have implemented it but now I am not able to select any row and this.selectedRows is empty.?

Comment: @IndreshBhargav did you put the correct field name for `Id`? Check the updated code.

Comment: Okay I have changed it to ```Id```. Now I have got the values in ```this.selectedRows``` but after I use ```selected-rows={selectedRows}``` on my html i am not able to select any row. The row does not gets checked when I click on it.

Comment: @IndreshBhargav do you see any errors on the console? can you put the updated code in the question?

Comment: no there is no error on the console although when I click on checkbox they do not get selected but ```this.selectedRows``` gets printed. Also it only stores one ID in this case. If I remove my html code then it is working fine but again rows are not retained.

Comment: @IndreshBhargav have you defined `selectedRows` at the class level?

Comment: Yes. I have defined it like this ```@track selectedRows = [];```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120657/discussion-between-rahul-gawale-and-indresh-bhargav).

Answer (score 0):

As you have decided to use id as the key field in the data table `key-field="id"` the data you are passing to the data table is expected to have id property on each row so row selection is not persistent.

**HTML**

```
<lightning-datatable key-field="id" data={tableData} columns={columns}
    onrowselection={handleRowSelection}>
</lightning-datatable>
```

**JS**

You need to set the id property in the table data. It is recommended to start the id from 1 to n.

```
let rowId = 0;
this.tableData = Array.from(caseNumberSet).map((caseNumber) => {
    rowId++;
    return { caseNumber: caseNumber, id: rowId};
});
```